# Flutter strange depfile error. Debug button disappearing in vs code

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-build

I am getting error while running my flutter app. I was working on my app and it was working perfectly fine but then out of nowhere, my app stopped working. I thought of running it again but then I started to encounter strange error. Also the debug button in vs code was disappeared.

It was a normal toDo app which was using hive to store data for todo. The app was perfectly running fine untill I added hive.delete() function in floatinActionBar button just to check if it deletes and then I could not hot reload or restart. out of a sudden, my debug button in vs code disappeared and I could not run the app even with flutter run command.

This is my error:

> Invalid depfile: D:\Shourya's Folder\Mobile Development\Flutter\todo_app.dart_tool\flutter_build\c16af2248f48b25154ee097cb0bd9d03\kernel_snapshot.d
> Invalid depfile: D:\Shourya's Folder\Mobile Development\Flutter\todo_app.dart_tool\flutter_build\c16af2248f48b25154ee097cb0bd9d03\kernel_snapshot.d
> Unhandled exception:
> FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ajs_interop_unsafe; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
>
> > #0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
> > #1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:732:37)
> > #2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:870:21)
> >
> > #3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:676:9)
> >
> > #4      starter (package:frontend_server/starter.dart:102:12)
> >
> > #5      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/x/w/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:13:14)
>
> Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 21s
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             23.1s
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried running

`flutter upgrade`

I could then run other apps perfectly fine but not the original one I got error while working on. I tried building another flutter app and copy pasting the code files but the error continued.

Comment: Without a minimal reproducible expample nobody can answer the question. You can learn more in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example